# Attaching a texture for the depth buffer

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, framebuffer

When I uncomment this line:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _depthMapTexture, 0);
```

I get error `0x8cd6` (incomplete framebuffer).
My texture is:

```
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
  glGenTextures(1, &_bestSADTexture);
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _bestSADTexture);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL);
```

I cannot find any combination of parameters or any example on Google that makes it work. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Found the combo:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

The debugger says this is a 24bit buffer. The values are only between 0 and 1, but I'd need a full range, can I not use a float texture instead?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how the depth buffer works? It's fixed-point unless you explicitly request floating-point. The fact that the values it can represent are between **0.0** and **1.0** does not mean you need a floating-point format. A depth of **1.0** will map to *0x00FFFFFF* and **0.0** will map to *0x00000000* (0.24-bit fixed-point).

Comment: No, I was using the depth buffer in a non-standard way: I have a texture with float values that I want to use as a depth buffer, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can effectively do that if you stretch a quad over the screen, sample the floating-point texture and then write `gl_FragDepth` in a fragment shader to fill the depth buffer with the values from that texture. That'll break hardware optimizations on a lot of hardware particularly TBDR but there's no reason it cannot be done.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I'm doing now. You are right it breaks hw optimizations, that was the reason I was trying to use the depth buffer, enabling depth test to skip some fragment calculations. I'm doing this for a computer vision task, you could say it's a weird application of the depth buffer.

Comment: Now I am instead stuck with a conditional in the fragment shader, which is not nice.